# Recommendations for good 'paging' and 'tagging' plugins/gems in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an app that will have galleries of thumbnail images to browse through. Potentially thousands or more. I am looking for recommendations on any existing plugins or gems for paging through large result sets and, for example, showing 50 thumbnails on a page with a link to show the next 50 and so on.

Second, I want to organize these with tags (and other things). I would also like suggestions on good ways to be able to filter the thumbnail gallery based on desired tag(s).

I know this is broadly asked... I am looking for your ideas!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [Ruby Toolbox](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/)

It shows you what gems are available and which are popular choices. In your case: will_paginate and acts-as-taggable-on